# Iptables - allow traffic from entire 10.x.x.x

Tags: iptables, firewall

Is there any way to configure iptables to ACCEPT the traffic from 10.anything?

currently I have the rule to the single address, but I want the entire range:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT --src 10.240.74.164 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

How would I need to change my above rule?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can simply write this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Source and destination rules accept CIDR notation.  Also, `-m tcp` is usually implicit (though including it is harmless), and `-s` is acceptable shorthand for `--src`.